# Do I want to (i)fft by gnuradio-companion?

Tags: fft, ifft, gnuradio-companion

To dark blue input ,Arrow becomes red.

Hi, everyone!
I use gnuradio-companion 3.7.11 with ubuntu 18.04.2 lts,
I want to do (I)FFT, but when both input and output specify complex,
Even if the complex is dark blue and complex is light blue,
It becomes an error when it becomes a red arrow.
I checked it myself, but I can not find the dark blue connector.
Please let us know if you know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're describing, but I think you're forgetting that the FFT expects a **vector** of samples as input, but you're providing it with single samples.

"Stream to vector" is the block that can remedy that.